# "Meiner Meinung nach" or "nach meiner Meinung"

Tags: preposition, phrase, word-order

We can use "meiner Meinung nach" to mean "in my opinion"

> Meiner Meinung nach ist es eine gute Idee, eine Fremdsprache zu lernen.

Can we say "nach meiner Meinung" instead?

> Nach meiner Meinung ist es eine gute Idee, eine Fremdsprache zu lernen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich würde das so sagen:

```
 Meiner Meinung nach ist es eine schöne Idee, eine Fremdsprache zu lernen.
```